# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/StreamExecutionEnvironment

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-flink

```scala
package com.knoldus
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time

object SocketWindowWordCount {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    var hostname: String = "localhost"
    var port: Int = 9000

    try {
     val params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
      hostname = if (params.has("hostname")) params.get("hostname") else "localhost"
      port = params.getInt("port")
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        System.err.println("No port specified. Please run 'SocketWindowWordCount " +
          "--hostname <hostname> --port <port>', where hostname (localhost by default) and port " +
          "is the address of the text server")
        System.err.println("To start a simple text server, run 'netcat -l <port>' " +
          "and type the input text into the command line")
        return
      }
    }

    // get the execution environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // get input data by connecting to the socket
    val text: DataStream[String] = env.socketTextStream(hostname, port, '\n')

    // parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
    val windowCounts = text
      .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
      .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1) }
      .keyBy("word")
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .sum("count")

    // print the results with a single thread, rather than in parallel
    windowCounts.print().setParallelism(1)

    env.execute("Socket Window WordCount")
  }

  /** Data type for words with count */

  case class WordWithCount(word: String, count: Long)

}
```

In the end while running this code on Intellij i am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/StreamExecutionEnvironment$
    at com.knoldus.SocketWindowWordCount$.main(SocketWindowWordCount.scala:43)
    at com.knoldus.SocketWindowWordCount.main(SocketWindowWordCount.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment$
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Can You extend the question with the dependencies ?

Comment: Do you have the Flink libraries on your classpath? How are you building and running your code? If you're using _SBT_, please post your build file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this by removing the `<scope>provided</scope>` which was present in the maven import.

Comment: Worked for me too. Very weird as scope had to be provided but that did not work as per official docs.

Answer (score 11):

Select menu item "Run" => "Edit Configurations...",
then in the "Build and run" section select "Modify options" => Java => Add dependencies with "Provided" scope to classpath in your local configuration.

In this way you don't have to remove the `<scope>provided</scope>`.

[image]