# flink-quickstart-java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No data sinks have been created yet

Tags: java, apache-flink, maven-archetype

I have just created new Flink project using maven archetype (i.e. template)
(Looking at [this](https://medium.com/big-data-processing/apache-flink-getting-started-part-1-3ac2206ccc96) article)

```
mvn archetype:generate                               \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink              \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-quickstart-java
```

1.14.4 is current version. The project can compile.
But when running either `BatchJob` or `StreamingJob`

```
public class BatchJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the batch execution environment
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
```

The first Exception NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment
can be solved as in [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/StreamExecutionEnvironment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809568/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-flink-streaming-api-scala-streamexecu)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment
    at com.example.flink.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

But then I get
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No data sinks have been created yet.`

P.S. All links to documentation https://flink.apache.org/docs/latest from these 2 Java classes are 404 Not Found,
so I guess this maven archetype was in fact abandoned and not updated for some time.

```
         * Have a look at the programming guide for the Java API:
         *
         * https://flink.apache.org/docs/latest/apis/batch/index.html
         *
         * and the examples
         *
         * https://flink.apache.org/docs/latest/apis/batch/examples.html
```

Comment: If you follow these instructions -- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/project-configuration/#maven-quickstart -- it should work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to docs Project Configuration - Maven Quickstart section. And that is exactly problem, and that project, which come with maven `flink-quickstart-java` archetype use, is in fact not runnable.
I went with Fraud Detection with the DataStream API example https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/datastream/ using `flink-walkthrough-datastream-java` and it just worked. See P.S. in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven quickstart does provide a properly setup skeleton project. However, the supplied applications aren't complete and don't run out of the box because they lack sources and sinks.

If you define a simple pipeline such as

```
env.fromElements(1, 2, 3).print();
```

then they will work.

Comment: This minimal line worked for both `ExecutionEnvironment` and `StreamExecutionEnvironment`